# Wait users click on popup with Rg.Plugins.Popup

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await, popup

I show a pop up and  I have to wait user's choice to put something in an entry control, the problem is that the if statment where I decide what goes as text in entry is executing at the same time as the popup shows.

I tried by making the method await but not working, here's what I have.

*Donesn't matter by now the if() statement,I was just trying*

This is my popup class (I want to wait until one of the buttons is clicked):

```
public partial class PopupElegirRFC  : PopupPage
{
    string sEmisor = "";
    string sReceptor = "";

    public PopupElegirRFC (string emisor, string receptor)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        lblREmisor.Text = "Emisor: " + emisor;
        lblRReceptor.Text = "Receptor: " + receptor;
        sEmisor = emisor;
        sReceptor = receptor;
    }

    private void BtnEmisor_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
        VGlobales.sRFSeleccionado = sEmisor;
    }

    private void BtnReceptor_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
        VGlobales.sRFSeleccionado = sReceptor;
    }
}
```

This is the code where I want to wait for users choice:

```
 case 2:

        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new Popups.PopupElegirRFC(list[0], list[1]));

         if (VGlobales.sRFSeleccionado == list[1])
            {
             RFCavalidar.Text = list[1];
             VGlobales.sRFSeleccionado = "";
             }
             else
             {
              RFCavalidar.Text = list[0];
              VGlobales.sRFSeleccionado = "";
              }

             break;
```

The code executes, but it goes directly to the if(), not waiting the user's choice

I would like to the popup to wait until some of both buttons in it is clicked. so I can make the if() validation

Comment: your popup page needs to raise an event or pass a message via MessagingCenter to let the calling page know that it's been dismissed.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but my answer can help someone.
Add TaskCompletionSource and wait for return.

Popup class:

```
public partial class PopupElegirRFC : PopupPage
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<string> taskCompletionSource;
    public Task<string> PopupClosedTask { get { return taskCompletionSource.Task; } }

    string sEmisor = "";
    string sReceptor = "";

    public PopupElegirRFC (string emisor, string receptor)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblREmisor.Text = "Emisor: " + emisor;
        lblRReceptor.Text = "Receptor: " + receptor;
        sEmisor = emisor;
        sReceptor = receptor;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing ()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    }

    private void BtnEmisor_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(sEmisor);
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
    }

    private void BtnReceptor_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(sReceptor);
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
    }
}
```

Code where you want to wait:

```
        var popupElegirRFC = new Popups.PopupElegirRFC(list[0], list[1]);

        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(popupElegirRFC);

        string result = await popupElegirRFC.PopupClosedTask;
        if (result == list[1])
        {
            RFCavalidar.Text = list[1];
        }
        else
        {
            RFCavalidar.Text = list[0];
        }
```

This idea came from the link below:
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/116

Answer (score 0):

as jason suggested , you can use MessagingCenter  to evaluate whether which button is clicked or not.

In your  Button click in popup page

```
private void BtnEmisor_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send((App)Application.Current,"BtnEmisor_Clicked");
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
        VGlobales.sRFSeleccionado = sEmisor;
    }
```

In your non- Popup page

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe((App)Application.Current, "BtnEmisor_Clicked", (sender) => 
    {

// Do task on that button click
    });
```

Comment: It worked but the code still executes the parts after the popup. And also you need to change this: MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>((App) ...

Comment: Did you execute the code after the popup inside the subscription?(MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>((App) )